# How to use sed or awk to extract a field from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm starting with the below list in file1.

```
** server can't find bla.bla.com: NXDOMAIN
** server can't find bla2.bla.com: NXDOMAIN
** server can't find bla3.bla.com: NXDOMAIN
** server can't find bla4.bla.com: NXDOMAIN
** server can't find bla5.bla.com: NXDOMAIN
```

I'd like to strip '** server can't find ' and ': NXDOMAIN' from each line and drop the results in a new file.

Results should look like -

```
bla.bla.com
bla2.bla.com
bla3.bla.com
bla4.bla.com
bla5.bla.com
```

I've tried the below sed commmand but I keep getting a > prompt.

```
sed '/\*\* server can't find /d' file1
```

Any ideas or better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quote is the problem. Try:

```
sed "s/\*\* server can't find \(.*\): NXDOMAIN/\1/" file1
```

which uses a capture group to grab the part of the line you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/\*\* server can't find /d' file1
```

is deleting the entire line

```
sed "s/\*\* server can't find //" file1
```

will replace the string with an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. single quotes can't be nested, you need to close the single quotes, escape a quote, and start them again: `'\''` or `'"'"'`. Another option is to switch to double quotes, but you mast be careful when the string contains characters with special meanings in double quotes (e.g. `$`).
2. `d` deletes the whole line, not just the matching part. Use substitution instead.

```
sed 's/\*\* server can'\''t find //;s/: NXDOMAIN//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

using awk:

```
cat 1.txt | awk '{print substr($5,0,index($5,":")-1)}'
bla.bla.com
bla2.bla.com
bla3.bla.com
bla4.bla.com
bla5.bla.com
```

Answer (score -1):

With GNU's `grep` you can use positive look ahead (`?=`):

```
 grep -oP '\S+(?=:)' inputfile
```

or with `perl`:

```
perl -nle 'print $& if m{\S+(?=:)}' inputfile
```